# pm2 in node.js throws error Cannot find module for require dotenv from command line

Tags: node.js, pm2

Here is my node.js script :

```
node -r dotenv/config server.js dotenv_config_path=qa.env
```

**NOTE : `-r dotenv/config` is require('dotenv') from command line. While dotenv_config_path=qa.env is command line args.**

I was trying the same in pm2 with

```
pm2 start  server.js  --node-args="-r dotenv/config dotenv_config_path=qa.env"
```

Throwing up " Error: Cannot find module /a/b/c/dotenv/config dotenv_config_path=qa.env "

How to fix the same in pm2.

Comment: did you try full path ? like ```--node-arges="-r /pathtoyoursource/dotenv/..."``` ?
It is better to config ```ecosystem``` file. See pm2 documentations.

Comment: it didn't worked : NOTE : -r dotenv/config is require('dotenv') from command line. while dotenv_config_path=qa.env is args